# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I has a popup block with code:

```
 <div class="popup_block" id="open-voucher">
     <div class="dialog-modal tech-support">

<div style="color: #fff;background: #232323;padding: 25px;text-align: center;">

                <div class="wrap-input" style="margin: 0 auto 15px;width: 253px;">
                    <input class="activate-voucher-input" type="text" placeholder="AAAAA-BBBBB-CCCCC-DDDDD-EEEEE-FFFFF">
                </div>
                <div style=""><button class="btn-yellow free-coins-btn btn-get-daily-bonus" type="submit">Activate</button></div>
            </div>

     </div>
 </div>
```

But when i press Activate button, my browser console thay error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined`.

My JS code:

```
        var el = $(this).parents('.popup_block').find('.btn-get-daily-bonus');
        var code = el.val().trim();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/promocode',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {code: code},
            success: function (data) {
                    showmessages(data.status, data.message);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                showmessages(err.status, err.message);
                console.log(err.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

How i can fix it?

**EDIT:**

I try edit code:

```
  <div class="dialog-modal tech-support">

<div style="color: #fff;background: #232323;padding: 25px;text-align: center;">

                <div class="wrap-input" style="margin: 0 auto 15px;width: 253px;">
                    <input class="activate-voucher-input" type="text" placeholder="AAAAA-BBBBB-CCCCC-DDDDD-EEEEE">
                </div>
                <div style=""><button class="btn-yellow activate-voucher-btn">Activate</button></div>
            </div>

  </div>
</div>
And
```

```
    $(document).on("click", "activate-voucher-btn", function (t) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/promocode',
            data: {
                voucher: $(".activate-voucher-input").val()
            },
            success: data => {
                $this.notify(data.type, data.message);
            }
        });
    });
```

But such a call also does not work, nothing happens. The console does not swear and the action is not performed.

Comment: Try this `$(this).parents('.popup_block').find('.activate-voucher-input')`, I think you'r using wrong selector

Comment: Buttons do not have a `value` property. So as ponury says, if you need to find the text the user typed into the input, use the correct selector.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function onActivate() {
  var el = $('#activate-voucher-input');
  var code = el.val().trim();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/promocode',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {code: code},
    success: function (data) {
            showmessages(data.status, data.message);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        showmessages(err.status, err.message);
        console.log(err.responseText);
    }
  });
}

function showmessages(status, message) {
  console.log(status, message);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup_block" id="open-voucher">
     <div class="dialog-modal tech-support">

<div style="color: #fff;background: #232323;padding: 25px;text-align: center;">

                <div class="wrap-input" style="margin: 0 auto 15px;width: 253px;">
                    <input id="activate-voucher-input" type="text" placeholder="AAAAA-BBBBB-CCCCC-DDDDD-EEEEE-FFFFF">
                </div>
                <div style=""><button onclick="onActivate()" class="btn-yellow free-coins-btn btn-get-daily-bonus" type="submit">Activate</button></div>
            </div>

     </div>
 </div>
```

You need to find element by ID. Actually `$('.class-name')` will return array of elements with that `class-name` and `el.val()` could be `undefined`.

Comment: i received `el.val is not a function` and `onActivate is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

I guess that is what you were trying to do

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var el = $(this).parents('.popup_block').find('.activate-voucher-input')[0];
  var code = $(el).val().trim();
  console.log(code);
  $.ajax({
    url: '/promocode',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {code: code},
    success: function (data) {
      showmessages(data.status, data.message);
    },
    error: function (err) {
      showmessages(err.status, err.message);
      console.log(err.responseText);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup_block" id="open-voucher">
  <div class="dialog-modal tech-support">

    <div style="color: #fff;background: #232323;padding: 25px;text-align: center;">

      <div class="wrap-input" style="margin: 0 auto 15px;width: 253px;">
        <input class="activate-voucher-input" type="text" placeholder="AAAAA-BBBBB-CCCCC-DDDDD-EEEEE-FFFFF">
      </div>

      <div style="">
        <button class="btn-yellow free-coins-btn btn-get-daily-bonus" type="submit">Activate</button>
      </div>
    
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: every time received `el.val is not a function`

Comment: `el.val()` *is* not a function, you have to do either `$(el).val()` whitch is jQuery either `el.value` which is pure JS